# VS 2008 to VS2012 migration giving macro redefinition warnings

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sdk, macros, warnings

I am working with Win7 x64 system; multiple VC++ and C# projects and have moved from VS2008 to VS2012. Now I am getting warnings saying:-

```
--------------------
warning C4005: '__on_failure' : macro redefinition  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\sal.h    2883

warning C4005: '__useHeader' : macro redefinition   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\sal.h    2872

warning C4005: '__useHeader' : macro redefinition   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1\include\sal_supp.h 58
```

---

1. I have already tried changing platform toolset to v110_xp but its not working
2. When I added #undef code to the concerned files error was gone but that is not the way to do it.
3. Also I saw changing SDK include directory from v7.1A to $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath) 8.0 but didn't understand how to do it.

Comment: you can access include directories from the project properties

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2012 C++ warning C4005: '\_\_useHeader': macro redefinition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363929/vs2012-c-warning-c4005-useheader-macro-redefinition)