# Visual studio 2012: what is the name of an environment variable for this path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2012: like `$(VCInstallDir)` points to the directory where I have installed the Visual Studio. What is the name of an environment variable `$()` for this path: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include`. I want to know if any environment variable name is used by the Visual Studio for: `Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include`

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\UnitTest\lib above path becomes  $(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\lib

Answer (score 0):

The Standard SDK include path variable is $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath).
Afaik this will resolve to the latest installed SDK version. If that is 6.0A in your case it will resolve to the desired path.

Regards
Michael

Comment: cannot open/ include shfolder.h error generated when i gave path  $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include

Comment: To clarify: $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath) is already the path to the include directory. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322979/where-is-windowssdk-includepath-defined] to see where that variable is defined.