# Why windows-sdk can not be linked properly when use cl or msbuild?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I use VS2017 to build some c++ projects and it goes successfully. When I build some libraries with `MSBuild`, `cl` or qt-creator with msvc tools , there are always errors of "can not open include file",and these missing include files all locate in `Windows Kit`, such as:

```
e:\workspace\boost_1_70_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(71): fatal error C1083: can not open include file: "ctype.h": No such file or directory
e:\workspace\boost_1_70_0\tools\build\src\engine\strings.h(11): fatal error C1083: can not open include file: "stddef.h": No such file or directory
order.c
e:\workspace\boost_1_70_0\tools\build\src\engine\modules\../mem.h(67): fatal error C1083: can not open include file: "stdlib.h": No such file or directory
```

I have searched for solutions and finally find one for qt: when I add the following two lines, qt-creator with msvc tools can build successfully:

```
win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += "F:\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.17763.0\\ucrt\\"
    LIBS += -L"F:\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.17763.0\\ucrt\\x86\\"
}
```

and for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322979/where-is-windowssdk-includepath-defined), I have checked `user.props`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup />
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

It is obviously that something went wrong with `WindowsSDKVersion`, `WindowsSDK_IncludesPath`, `WindowsSDK_LibraryPath` or something else about Windows SDK. But this prombles dosen't exist until this year. I have no ideal what happend.

Is there any way to correct `WindowsSDK_IncludesPath`and `WindowsSDK_LibraryPath`, or at least make it possible to use msbuild and cl?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the SDK.  The CRT got split in two in 2015, intention was to give UWP programs their own copy of the CRT, distributed by Windows Update.  Why your qt-creator copy doesn't know this is unguessable, maybe it is old and you'll have to update it.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused...but when I use VS2017(GUI) nothing goes wrong. And it seems that if I want to update CRT I need to update windows?(The windows update works well)

Answer (score 0):

Well...I find a "dirty" solution finally:
I edit the `vcvarsall.bat`, change the default value of `__VCVARSALL_WINSDK` to my target WindowsSDK version:
[image]
(`%WindowsSDKVersion%` is an environment variable I set before)

It seems that everything works well...hope so