# WindowsSDK_Include not defined for 32bit release build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I am having a problem trying to find out where WindowsSDK_Include is defined.  I have multiple projects where it is defined for 64-Bit Release mode, 64-Bit debug mode, 32-Bit Debug mode, but *not* 32-Bit release mode.  I've looked at [Where is WindowsSDK_IncludePath defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322979/where-is-windowssdk-includepath-defined) and [SDKDDKVer.h missing, but WinSDK installed? (c++ header issues)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390539/sdkddkver-h-missing-but-winsdk-installed-c-header-issues/29818137#29818137).  Under my build Properties it is part of my include path everywhere it is defined, but for 32-Bit release mode I have $(WindowsSdk_71A_IncludePath) instead.  I am looking to get the VersionHelpers.h which is part of the Windows8.1 SDK and greater.