# 'sdkddkver.h' file not found in pip install MetaTrader5

Tags: python

It happens when i tried to use command "pip install MetaTrader5" on Python 3. I'm using Mac OS. Is there compability issue here?. Because when i tried that pip install command. it throws error :

```js
building 'MetaTrader5.C' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/src
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/src/Interprocess
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/src/Connector
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DUNICODE -Isrc -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/galihlarasprakoso/Projects/Python/MetaTraderBot/venv/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/MetaTrader.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/src/MetaTrader.o
    In file included from src/MetaTrader.cpp:6:
    src/stdafx.h:16:10: fatal error: 'sdkddkver.h' file not found
    #include <sdkddkver.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're working with a linux machine. Seems to me like the package was built specifically for windows environment.

Related:
[SDKDDKVer.h missing, but WinSDK installed? (c++ header issues)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390539/sdkddkver-h-missing-but-winsdk-installed-c-header-issues)
https://github.com/AudioNet/node-core-audio/issues/4